# Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded (works with other columns)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have saved foreign text in database under name column in users table and it throws Malformed UTF-8 errors but strange thing that is happening when I swap the values with another column only then its working.

| name | username |
| --- | --- |
| 村田篤郎 | happiness |
| John Doe | jdoe |

the above User table structure causes error while if I swap as shown below it works.

| name | username |
| --- | --- |
| happiness | 村田篤郎 |
| John Doe | jdoe |

Database collation is `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` and User table has (name =utf8_unicode_ci , username = utf8_unicode_ci) collation.

Laravel eloquent query

```
User::withTrashed()->notAdmin()->select('id', 'email', 'name', 'profile_picture', 'created_at', 'deleted_at', 'is_active', 'email_verified_at', 'provider')
            ->withCount(['campaigns', 'inactivecampaigns', 'activecampaigns'])
            ->orderBy('created_at')
            ->get();
```

User.php

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable, SoftDeletes;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    protected  $keyType = 'string';
    public $incrementing = false;
...
```

config/database.php

```
<?php
return [
    'connections' => [
        'mysql' => [
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ]

    ]
];
```

When swapped it worked and my guess is `name` column is serializing from somewhere else but I couldn't find anything within code.

Comment: Charsets, when not explicitly set, are inherited. Tables from the database settings, and individual columns from the table settings. If you set the table charset incorrectly, [eg: utf8] defined the `name` column, then changed the table charset [eg utf8mb4] and defined the `username` column it would likely result in this behaviour. Running a `SHOW CREATE TABLE` should show where the charsets are mismatched.

Comment: "it throws Malformed UTF-8 errors" -- when Inserting?  When Selecting?  Can you get the hex of the offending string?

Comment: @RickJames when selecting. that is the hex `E69D91E794B0E7AFA4E9838E09 ` of 村田篤郎
and its not just the Chinese but Spanish as well.

Comment: @Sammitch I checked it with `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the charsets are identical for the columns username and name, in-fact all of the columns. `name varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,`

Comment: @danish-khan-I - the HEX looks like proper utf8 (except for the tab-09 on the end).  Both Chinese and Spanish will be fine.  The CREATE looks good, too.  So I don't know where (in Laravel) the error is coming from.

Comment: @RickJames I am going to try it on the new table with same charset and see if it works. that's quite strange though :(

Comment: @danish-khan-I - Yeah, there are a lot of moving parts.  We are missing some step somewhere.